# Creating models in the Angular 5/6

Tags: json, angular

I have some issue with the displaying answer from backend (JSON). This is my json from server:

```
{
"items": [
 {
    "countryId": 1,
    "countryName": "Особь без подданства",
    "countryIdEDBO": -1,
    "countryIsArchive": 0
},
{
    "countryId": 2,
    "countryName": "Австрал",
    "countryIdEDBO": 36,
    "countryIsArchive": 0
}
     ],
"_links": {
"self": {
    "href": "http://...."
},
"next": {
    "href": "http://...."
},

"last": {
    "href": "http://...."
}
},
"_meta": {
"totalCount": 247,
"pageCount": 13,
"currentPage": 1,
"perPage": 20
},
}
```

Before displaying json massive from backend, we must create models of this json in the Angular 5/6. Using service http://jvilk.com/MakeTypes/ for generate models of JSON and insert in my code.
This is model of JSON:

```js
export interface Country {
  items?: (ItemsEntity)[] | null;
  _links: Links;
  _meta: Meta;
}
export interface ItemsEntity {
  countryId: number;
  countryName: string;
  countryIdEDBO: number;
  countryIsArchive: number;
}
export interface Links {
  self: SelfOrNextOrLast;
  next: SelfOrNextOrLast;
  last: SelfOrNextOrLast;
}
export interface SelfOrNextOrLast {
  href: string;
}
export interface Meta {
  totalCount: number;
  pageCount: number;
  currentPage: number;
  perPage: number;
}
```

This is my code in the Component:

```js
export class CountryComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _preloadService: PreloadService, private countryService:CountryService) { }

  country:Country;

  ngOnInit() {
    //пока что undefined возвращает в консоль вывода
    this.getListCountry();
    console.log(this.country);    
  }

  getListCountry(){
     this.countryService.getCountryList().subscribe((data:Country)=>(this.country=data));
  }
```

So, the answer in the console of browser is "Undefined". What i supposed to do? I know, that the problem in the model, so maybe u know links or answer how i must create model for my JSON answer from server?

Comment: It is `undefined` because the previous line calls a method where you are asynchronously loading the variable. You are logging it before the response comes back from the server

Comment: **Asynchronous issue** : your console log happens before the end of your HTTP call. Make your console log into your `subscribe`.

Comment: Can someone tag it as duplicate ? I can't find another question, I don't know what terms to look for.

Comment: do `console.log(this.country)` below `this.country=data`

Comment: Ok, thx. My problem is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Just put the "console.log()" into method of get answer fromv service

```js
export class CountryComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _preloadService: PreloadService, private countryService:CountryService) { }

  country:Country;

  ngOnInit() {
    //пока что undefined возвращает в консоль вывода
    this.getListCountry();    
  }

  getListCountry(){
     this.countryService.getCountryList().subscribe((data:Country)=>(console.log(data)));
  }
  }
```